How to add a custom global spellchecker (Esperanto language) on macOS?
Esperanto is an artificially constructed language which has about 2 millions speakers globally. Understandably, macOS doesn't come with an Esperanto language dictionary / spellchecker preinstalled. I've compiled a list of roughly 70,000 Esperanto words in a .dic format.
Going to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Clicking on "Edit" in Input Sources -> Spelling, at the bottom it shows "Set Up..."

The setup dialog specifies that additional spelling dictionaries can be added to the Library/Spelling folder in the format of .dic and .aff

I've copied my Esperanto .dic and .aff files to that location. It then shows as an option in the Spelling section, which I ensure to select

With that being said, spellcheck does not work. Opening up "Pages" application, all my Esperanto words are still underlined with red squiggles. In Pages I've even specified the "Esperanto (Library)" in the spellcheck, and it still doesn't seem to register.
These are the dictionary files (.dic, .aff) I am currently using: REMOVED
This is the tutorial I was following
What am I doing wrong?
Edit: I called Apple support this morning. I spoke to a senior advisor and he was not aware of how to correctly configure my own custom spellchecker on Mac.
Edit #2: Solved. Check out this tutorial on how to configure it:
https://github.com/nhershy/EsperantoSpellcheckMacOS

It is possible that Apple simply silently removed this less-used feature. Can you test it on earlier versions of macOS?

Try using the already made files for Esperanto at https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/esperantilo-spell-check-grammar-checker-and-thesaurus-esperanto-language .  See this page for info:  https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250005161

Thank you, Using the OpenOffice .aff and .dic files did the trick. My .aff file was not in the correct format. I created a tutorial for anyone else interested in doing this. Attached above

Glad you found a solution to your problem! Instead of editing in that you found the solution, please use the "Answer" field to add your solution. Additionally, a link to a tutorial would be considered a "link-only" answer. Since it is your tutorial, consider placing that tutorial as the "Answer".
